# read in solaris going to an infinite loop

Tags: shell, sh, solaris, solaris-10

```
# cat test.sh
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh
while true; do
read -p "do you want to continue (Y/N) ?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo " Yes "; 
        [Nn]* ) echo " No "; exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
echo "execution completed..."
```

The above test script goes to infinite loop but it works fine if I use `/usr/bin/bash`.

How to make this script to make it working in `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`?
Please help I'm new to shell scripting and no idea about POSIX and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/): `In POSIX sh, read -p is undefined.`

Replace

```
read -p "do you want to continue (Y/N) ?" yn
```

by

```
printf "%s" "do you want to continue (Y/N) ?"
read yn
```

Comment: Even: `printf "do you want to continue (Y/N) ?"`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use sed command to replace a line if some string is matched in that line ?

Comment: @AlenPeter: `sed 's/.*some string.*/new line/' file`